# android lifecycle issue while loading my app

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-signin

I have a query regarding the Activity lifecycle(very new to android development)
I have a method that calls MainActivity.java.
In the MainActivity I have set up my google login.
Currently as soon as I run my app it displays the google sign-in pop-up.
I want it to display only when my method is called. I have linked the "getAuthorizations" method to a button in my JS file. When I click the button, this method is invoked and then the google sign-in pop up should display.
Clearly onCreate is no the correct way.
Need help here!!

Method:

```
//Custom function that we are going to export to JS
    @ReactMethod
    public void getAuthorizations() {
        try{
            new MainActivity();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("error", "error!!!!");
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    private static String TAG = "myHealth";

      @Override
      protected String getMainComponentName() {
          return "MyHealth";
        }

      private FitnessOptions fitnessOptions;
      int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setFitnessOption();
        checkFitInstalled();
      }

      public void checkFitInstalled() {
        if (isGoogleFitPermissionGranted()) {
          // do whatever you need here
        } else {
          requestGoogleFitPermission();
        }
      }

      public boolean isGoogleFitPermissionGranted() {
        if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      public void setFitnessOption() {
        fitnessOptions =
                FitnessOptions.builder()
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
                        .build();
      }

      public void requestGoogleFitPermission() {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                account,
                fitnessOptions);
      }
}
```

**Update (as per answer):**

```
@ReactMethod
    public void getAuthorizations() {
        try{
   // create Intent and start activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("error", "error!!!!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to native programing :-)
if you want to open another activity any where in your activity you must declare an Intent object and identify the origin and destination activity, for instance:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

startActivty(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! So I need to do this in my method right?? (check my updated code at the end of my question). Then should I remove the onCreate from mainActivity? How do I invoke my function "setFitnessOption()"?

Comment: That's right.onCreate() is the first method in activitie's lifeCycle that will be executed after you start your new activity so you can call your method in it and it will be executed right after you opened your new activity.I suggest you to read about android lifecycle.it will help you a lot. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle